# All items in my pen drive had been renamed automatically and cannot open it

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive

All the items (both files and folders) inside my pen drive had been renamed to some characters like **:]h.¡>?.A╕╗** and when I try to open any folder Windows gives this message.

**The filename,directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect**

I was told that it is a problem of the pen drive, not a virus. They say if I format the pendrive then I will be able to use it again normally. But I'm not sure. And I need those files.

Does anybody know a solution?

Comment: before doing anything like repair or whatsoever, if you really need the files you could do a backup using dd with a linux live system. I've also seen several times a filesystem which could not be read with windows was readable from linux.

Answer (score 0):

your system may be infected with virus.

Install Avast antivirus with latest updates and try to run boottime scan option in avast.

Comment: He was told it is not a virus. Also, that wouldn't help him get his files back.